# Area of rhombus formed at the intersection of 2 circles

Tags: geometry, circles, area, quadrilateral

Consider 2 circles with radius r. Question is to find the area of the rhombus formed by joining the intersections. The edges of rhombus are the centers of the 2 circles and the 2 intersecting points.

[picture of circle intersecting with rhombus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnVC5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have two equilateral triangles, since the angles are all 60º. You only have to compute the height of one of the triangles with Pythagoras theorem, and then apply
$$
A=\frac{bh}{2}
$$

Finally, multiply by 2.